# Gdb conditional step based on memory address?

Tags: gdb

I 'm wondering if it 's possible to create a script that will continue the program 's execution (after a break) step by step based on the memory address value.
So, if I 'm tracing a function and it goes into a high memory value, I 'd call the gdb script until the memory value is below a set value - then it would break again.

I 'm very new to gdb and still reading the manual/tutorials, but I 'd like to know if my goal is possible :) - and if you could bump me to the proper direction, even better ;)

Thanks!

Edit, updated with pseudocode:

```
while (1) {
    cma = getMemoryAddressForCurrentInstruction();
    if (cma > 0xdeadbeef) {
        stepi;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "the memory address value" is vague, but I think you're looking for a watchpoint. `watch *(int *)0x12345678` for example watches the int at address 0x12345678. Then you can just `cont` the program and it'll run until that value changes.

Comment: @AlanCurry: I updated the question with pseudocode of what I 'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the [Program Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) (sometimes called the instruction pointer). It's available in gdb as `$pc`. Your pseudocode can be translated into this actual gdb command:

```
while $pc <= 0xdeadbeef
    stepi
```

It'll be slow, since it's starting and stopping the program for every instruction, but as far as I know there's no fast way to do it if you don't know exactly what address you're looking for. If you do, then you can just set a breakpoint there:

```
break *0xf0abcdef
cont
```

will run until the program counter hits 0xf0abcdef